# error no instance of overloaded function "calMean" matches the argument list

Tags: c, file, structure

I'm having error saying that no instance of overloaded function "calMean" matches the argument list

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME  20
#define LIST_SIZE 50

float calMean(RECORD list[], int count)

typedef struct 
{
    char *name;
    int  score;
}RECORD;


int main (void)
{
    // Declarations
       float mean;
       FILE *fp;
       char fileName[FILE_NAME];
       RECORD list[LIST_SIZE];
       char buffer[100];
       int count = 0;
       int i;
    // Statements
       printf("Enter the file name: ");
       gets(fileName);

       fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

       if(fp == NULL)
           printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
         while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
          {
             if( count >= LIST_SIZE)
             {
                printf("Only the first 50 data will be read!\n");
                break;
             }
             if( count < LIST_SIZE)
             {
                list[count].name = (char*) malloc(strlen(buffer)*sizeof(char));
                sscanf(buffer,"%[^,], %d", list[count].name, &list[count].score);
                printf("name is %s and score is %d\n", list[count].name, list[count].score);
                count++;
             }
             for( i =0; i < (LIST_SIZE - count); i++)
             {   
             list[count + i].name = 0;
             list[count + i].score = 0;
             }
          }
       printf("Read in %d data records\n", count);  
       mean = calMean(list, count);        
       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
}


float calMean(RECORD list[], int count)
{
    float tempMean;
    int sum;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sum += list[i].score;
    tempMean = sum/count;

    return tempMean;
}
```

The error occur at the function call for calMean function in main, I'm new to structure so I think that the way I write list argument list in calMean function call was wrong, is there anyway to fix this? I'm trying to calculate the average of member score in structure.

Comment: Try removing the `&` from `&count`.

Comment: Note also that it sounds like you're trying to compile C code as if it were C++, hence the C++ error message - change the .cpp suffix to .c for more meaningful C-specific error messages.

Comment: actually that what i did before but it still showing the same error, also my source file is .c not .cpp

Comment: Are you sure this is C?  There aren't overloaded functions in C in general, but there are in C++.  Are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler (maybe MSVC on Windows)?

Comment: i thought that too I never heard of overloaded function in C before only in java and C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is interesting.  What you show is not the code you are compiling, which is always bad news.  What you have is:

```
float calMean(RECORD list[], int count);  // semicolon missing in original

typedef struct 
{
    char *name;
    int  score;
}RECORD;

...

float calMean(RECORD list[], int count)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that the type `RECORD` is somehow redefined — without causing a compilation error — between the time when `calMean()` is first declared and when it is defined.

This means you have two declarations for `calMean()`, but they refer to different types in the first parameter.  Hence the claim of 'overloading'.

You must be using a C++ compiler.

I can't think of a way that you can write the code as shown, so that `RECORD` changes meaning like that.  I tried this code:

```
struct RECORD { int x; };

float calMean(RECORD list[], int count);

typedef struct { int y; } RECORD;

float calMean(RECORD list[], int count);
```

But G++ 4.7.1 said:

```
x.cpp:5:31: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct RECORD RECORD’
x.cpp:1:12: error: ‘struct RECORD’ has a previous declaration as ‘struct RECORD’
```

Comment: Does your source file have a `.c` suffix (i.e. C source file) or a `.C` or `.cpp` suffix (i.e. C++ source file)

Comment: It was `.cpp` as in the error message.  I didn't try it as C code; maybe I should? 'Twas late last night...

Comment: With GCC (instead of G++) on `x.c` instead of `x.cpp`, I get the error `x.c:3:15: error: unknown type name ‘RECORD’`, which is what I'd expect.  You only get a plain type `RECORD` from `struct RECORD` in C++, which is why I was using the `.cpp` extension.  Obviously, this is not MSVC; that might do things differently.  (Compiler command line: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     -c x.c`)

Comment: thank I think I got it, the reason why it is showing the error was because it put my function prototype before the typedef declaration

Comment: That's part of it, for sure; the puzzle (to me) is why you weren't getting an error when the prototype was before the typedef.